# Permission issues using terminal for ruby rails an rubymine

Tags: ruby, macos, permissions, rubygems, terminal

Just started learning ruby on rails. Currently trying to install a few gems having issues with permission

```
Last login: Tue Dec  4 19:21:30 on ttys000
unknown-00-1c-b3-c0-49-e2:~ Wushu$ gem install
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)
unknown-00-1c-b3-c0-49-e2:~ Wushu$
```

I use the mac os x 10.6.
I tried a cleaning my permissions using utility on my mac and still get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be:

```
 gem install << name of gem here >>
```

Not just:

```
 gem install
```

-- EDIT --

A better approach that installing your individual gems, would be to use bunder. If, of course, you're using Ruby on Rails.

In your gemfile, add the relevant gems:

source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.10'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

And then run

```
bundle install
```

Within your Rails Application root

Comment: Thanks Simon even though that works i still get the issue trying to install a few gems.

Comment: Another point, how come you're not using bundler to update your gems within your application??

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using sudo to try to install gems as it could lead to weird behavior

Comment: I agree with Leo Correa that sudo is bad but would resolve the permissions issue. Mix the bundler suggestion I made with Leo's suggestion to use RVM and you'll be on to a winner.

Answer (score 0):

Like @simonmorley said you should definitely use the Gemfile in the rails application to handle installing gems and such along with bundler.

You might also want to look into rvm to manage ruby versions and gemsets for different projects.

As for your error you need to provide a gem name when doing the command `gem install <some_gem_name>` Notice that gem won't be run in the context of your Rails application and when you decide to use your app in another computer/server it won't know to use that gem you are installing. So like I said, include it in your Gemfile and it will save you any trouble later on.